# How to remove App Service using Azure Automation

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

The following code works great via Azure Cloud Shell (*completes, App Service deleted as expected*).

```
Remove-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup1" -Name "AppService1" -Force
```

It also completes without error within my Runbook workflow, but the App Service remains operational. This feels like a permissions problem, but I've tried adding the Owner role at the subscription level without success.

Any ideas/tips for how to make this work for the AzureRunAsConnection account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This feels like a permissions problem, but I've tried adding the Owner role at the subscription level without success.

It is not a permission problem, when you create the automation account along with the RunAsAccount, it will add the service principal related to the RunAsAccount to the subscription as a `Contributor` role, which is enough to remove the web app.

If you are using the `PowerShell Workflow Runbook`, try the sample below, it works for me. (First, make sure you have installed the `Az.Accounts`, `Az.Websites` modules in the automation account -> `Modules`.)

```
workflow testrun3
{
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    try
    {
        # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
        $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

        Connect-AzAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
    }
    catch {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }

    Remove-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "<group-name>" -Name "joywebapp1234" -Force
}
```

[image]

**Check the result in the portal:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy! Your example was nearly identical to what I had been working with, so that forced me to really re-look at every character and I had a typo in the App Service name.  Turns out the Remove-AzWebApp method completes without error or any mention of the App Service not existing.

Answer (score 0):

To create or update a Run As account, you must have specific privileges and permissions. An `Application administrator` in Azure Active Directory and an `Owner in a subscription` can complete all the tasks. Use [`Remove-AzAutomationConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/remove-azautomationconnection?view=azps-3.8.0) to remove an Automation connection.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account#permissions) about Run As account permissions.